# Узнать расстояние по Google API когда больше 2 точек

Tags: google-maps-api

Для того что бы рассчитать расстояние между двумя точек это просто

```
$data[] = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Kyiv&destination=Lviv&sensor=false'));
```

а вот как сделать если точек больше чем 2 вот так не работает

```
$data[] = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Kyiv&destination=Lviv&waypoints=Vinnica&sensor=false'));
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать, что вы не хотите останавливаться в Виннице |via:Vinnica вместо waypoints=Vinnica.

Comment: извините но не работает,а где вы это нашли в доке. Сделал по другому сейчас выложу код

Comment: Я не был уверен, но см.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints

Comment: работает но как то это не то оно рисует какой то свой маршрут 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Киев&destination=Винница&waypoints=via:Житомир|via:Львов&sensor=false'));

Comment: вот как должно было выглядеть http://goo.gl/uhYaXz

Comment: а не все правильно оно нарисовало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал как то так

```
 $origin = null;
    $array = array(
        'Винница',
        'Житомир',
        'Львов',
        'Ужгород',
        'Тернополь',

        );
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($origin != null) {
            $data[$k]['origin'] = $origin;
            $data[$k]['destination'] = $v;
        }
        $origin = $v;
    }
    $distance = 0;

    foreach ($data as $ks => $vl) {

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' .
            $vl['origin'] . '&destination=' . $vl['destination'] . '&sensor=false'));

        foreach ($data->routes as $k => $v) {
            foreach ($v->legs as $ke => $va) {

                echo $va->start_address . '</br>';
                echo $va->end_address . '</br>';
                echo $va->distance->text . '</br>';

                echo '<hr/>';
                $distance = $va->distance->text + $distance;
            }

        }

    }
    echo $distance;
```